# How to pair Bluetooth device without confirmation

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth tag called "key finder" like this image: [Bluetooth tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMnAX.jpg)

This tag has more apps like "iTracing" working with it. The app searches for the tag, and when found, pairs it automatically without pin code and without any confirmation!

Does SDK support that and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pairing a device always requires user input.  This is to prevent the case where a malicious app tries to pair with a device that may operate against the desire of the user (for example, transmitting private audio and data to it).

Bluetooth Low Energy devices (like beacons) don't require pairing, but all they do is broadcast tiny bits of data periodically. Communication with BTLE devices like this are supported in KitKat and later as long as the app has permission to do so.

Comment: Thanks Doug for replying, could you set example to program BTLE